# Xcodebuild: [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug

Tags: xcode, swift, shell, xcodebuild, xcode-ui-testing

I try to run my test on a iphonesimulator with Xcodebuild but I get always the same errors.

My command line:

```
xcodebuild clean test -workspace App.xcworkspace -scheme "UI Tests" -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6,OS=9.2'
```

The stacktrace:

```
xcodebuild[31826:741511] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: (796137A0-CB6A-490D-BF89-767DF586BE26) Beginning test session 796137A0-CB6A-490D-BF89-767DF586BE26 with Xcode 7C68 on target <DVTiPhoneSimulator: 0x7fef34dce060> {
        SimDevice: SimDevice : iPhone 6 (ED6BBC90-CCD7-4AFE-ABBD-AFAE28B7EEC7) : state={ Booted } deviceType={ SimDeviceType : com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6 } runtime={ SimRuntime : 9.2 (13C75) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-9-2 }
} (9.2 (13C75))
2016-02-22 13:07:10.489 XCTRunner[32908:746212] Running tests...
2016-02-22 13:07:10.490 XCTRunner[32908:746212] Looking for test bundles in /Users/me/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/ED6BBC90-CCD7-4AFE-ABBD-AFAE28B7EEC7/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/2D77EC0A-85FA-4C8B-BC62-27334E6278C5/UITests-Runner.app/PlugIns
2016-02-22 13:07:10.491 XCTRunner[32908:746212] Found test bundle at /Users/me/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/ED6BBC90-CCD7-4AFE-ABBD-AFAE28B7EEC7/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/2D77EC0A-85FA-4C8B-BC62-27334E6278C5/UITests-Runner.app/PlugIns/UITests.xctest
2016-02-22 13:07:10.492 XCTRunner[32908:746212] Looking for configurations in /Users/me/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/ED6BBC90-CCD7-4AFE-ABBD-AFAE28B7EEC7/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/2D77EC0A-85FA-4C8B-BC62-27334E6278C5/UITests-Runner.app/PlugIns/UITests.xctest
2016-02-22 13:07:10.494 XCTRunner[32908:746212] Found configuration <XCTestConfiguration: 0x7fd750623340>
                      testBundleURL:file:///Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-axxxxxxxxxxx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/UITests-Runner.app/PlugIns/UITests.xctest/
                  productModuleName:UITests
                        testsToSkip:UITests/test_App()
                         testsToRun:(null)
                 reportResultsToIDE:YES
                  sessionIdentifier:<__NSConcreteUUID 0x7fd750626d10> 796137A0-CB6A-490D-BF89-767DF586BE26
         pathToXcodeReportingSocket:(null)
          disablePerformanceMetrics:no
    treatMissingBaselinesAsFailures:no
                    baselineFileURL:(null)
              targetApplicationPath:/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-axxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/App.app
          targetApplicationBundleID:de.xxxxx
                   reportActivities:YES
           testsMustRunOnMainThread:YES
13:07:10.629 XCTRunner[32908:746223] _XCT_testBundleReadyWithProtocolVersion:minimumVersion: reply received
13:07:10.635 XCTRunner[32908:746221] _IDE_startExecutingTestPlanWithProtocolVersion:16
2016-02-22 13:07:10.992 XCTRunner[32908:746212] Continuing to run tests in the background with task ID 1
Test Suite 'Selected tests' started at 2016-02-22 13:07:11.557
Test Suite 'UITests.xctest' started at 2016-02-22 13:07:11.558
Test Suite 'UITests.xctest' passed at 2016-02-22 13:07:11.558.
     Executed 0 tests, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 0.000 (0.000) seconds
** TEST FAILED **
```

When I call the test direct on Xcode, I have any problems.

Any ideas?
Thank for helping.

Cheers.

Comment: Are you sure that scheme should be UI Tests? Look at the docs example: xcodebuild test -project MyAppProject.xcodeproj -scheme MyApp -destination 'platform=Simulator,name=iPhone,OS=8.1'

Comment: With xcodebuild -list i can list all my scheme in this project. This scheme is available in the list. I think, the command line is correct.

Comment: @emoleumassi Are your tests added to ```UI Tests``` target ?